# How can I make this bevel and emboss effect look deeper

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am trying to design an image which looks like this:

[image]

But I ended up with the following image: (edited image)

[image]

I tried adding layer styles as in the below image (Edited image).

[image]

How can I make the second image look deeper, like the first does?

Edited one :

[image]

with this new bevel settings

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key is that you're doing the Bevel and Emboss a little bit backwards.

To replicate that image, I would instead apply the Bevel and Emboss to a wood panel that has the area "punched out":

[image: Wood with area punched out]

We still need something for the backdrop, so I duplicated the original layer and offset it by a few pixels down and to the right (this will help with the depth effect in the finished product)

[image: Both layers]

To the top layer, I will apply the Bevel and Emboss (using [these settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYjXn.png))

[image: Bevel and Emboss]

We're still not fully there, the original image has a lot more depth. There are two final touches to make. The first is to add a drop shadow to the top layer to really bring it out (I used [these settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiEtK.png)):

[image: Drop shadow applied]

The final touch is to darken the bottom/background layer. I used an adjustment layer, but there are of course many ways to do that. Here's what the finished product looks like:

[image: Finished product]

Comparison:

[image: comparison image]

Comment: Yeah this is what i want to do.. Thanks JohnB. I will start trying the procedure and will get back if i face any problem in doing it :) Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Would love to give +unlimited upvotes for the help

Answer (score 5):

Change settings of the bevel effect (do not forget its colors' blend mode.) also change the brightness of the wooden texture layer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried changing the bevel effect as you suggested. But the image is not still as i wished. Please find the edited image in the question. Cant it be done without changing the brightness of the image?

Comment: Your image size larger than example. Layer styles depends to size. Try it in same size.

Comment: Cant i get the same style if its of larger style?

Comment: You need to increase values of bevel

Comment: I would be thankful if you try to provide me step by step way to make the image look deeper. I even tried the same with a smaller one but this time i didnt even get that deeper feel. So could you please help me. Check the edited image Ferdi

Answer (score 4):

You need to click on the **Bevel and Emboss** option in your window. You are currently on the **Blending Options** general tab so you don't see the available options for beveling.

[image: Click on the Bevel and Emboss list item]

After you click on **Bevel & Emboss** you will see options to increase your **Depth**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried increasing the depth as you suggested. But the image is not still as i wished. Please find the edited image in the question.